# How can I search for transaction text on the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

Is there a google like search engine which can search for any text that is included with a bitcoin transaction? As I understand it each transaction includes 80 characters of text as well.

### Update

It is not possible to search the blockchain for text in an easy way

Comment: It isn't true that *every* transaction contains 80 bytes of text; this is an optional feature and used only occasionally. If you are running a full node such as Bitcoin Core, you could simply grep the block files; then the harder part is identifying the start and end of the transaction and computing its id.

Comment: There are several methods of sending text in bitcoin transactions. It is not nescessarily 80 characters. One method most often used, is to have a multisig transaction, where some of the publickeys contain the text, instead of being a valid public key.

Comment: Would it be useful to make a search engine for all of this? Maybe I should do that

Comment: It is possible to make search engine. But i doubt that it would be useful for something.

Comment: What about for searching through all those Digital Contract type uses of the Blockchain? I would have thought that was the killer app for Bitcoin?

Comment: Thanks, that makes alot of sense. So where will the actual data be stored if only the hash is stored on the BlockChain?

Comment: @AussieCryptocurrency. Add that comment as an answer and I will accept it and award the bounty, as I assume you have got the closest and most correct answer, even if what I wanted to do by searching the blockchain is not possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we're talking about smart contracts and such (which we are) then there's no text to search from contracts and such. The digital contract functionality doesn't work like Blockchain.info *comments*.

If you're going to use the Blockchain to lodge a patent for example, you're not uploading the actual patent. A hash is being made of the time (ie perhaps the hash of block at that height) and a hash of the document, which is then concatenated and then hashed again. So at it's simplest it's:

```
hash( hash(Blockchain time data) + hash(Document))
```

Think of it like this: the patent is in an envelope. The envelope is sealed with wax and stamped with a stamp referencing:

- proof of time and
- proof of envelope's contents

The text inside the envelope isn't searchable, whilst Blockchain.info comments (analogous to post-it notes in an accounting ledger) might be, though the usefulness is not the same.

Answer (score 6):

There is funny site http://bitcoinstrings.com/ I am not sure that it is what are you looking for but just in case...

Comment: Yes its funny. But it still doesn't let you search the blockchain

Comment: Are you interested in blockchain.info site messages? Try google advanced search like https://www.google.ru/search?q=clue+site:blockchain.info (this query for word "clue")

Comment: No, I am interested in blockchain transaction messages, not site messages

Comment: In fact, transactions do not have text fields. But there are some ways to include arbitrary data (text, images) in transaction. Read this article http://www.righto.com/2014/02/ascii-bernanke-wikileaks-photographs.html

Answer (score 3):

In fact that text is a [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info) extension not really present in the blockchain itself. I can't find any text search method in the [query API](https://blockchain.info/q).

Comment: I believe you are right, this is not possible right now to search the blockchain.

Answer (score 3):

I found that [smartbit.com.au](https://www.smartbit.com.au/) allows you to search for text included in `OP_RETURN` outputs.

As an example, searching for "on brink" returns an Eternity Wall message that echos the coinbase of the genesis block.

[image]

Comment: While it is hard to give a more comprehensive answer to this question than what is given, I think it could be improved by providing an example for a successful search.